# How do I escape characters in a vim abbreviation?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm trying to make this abbreviation in my Vimrc for markdown editing:
`iabbrev ,,img ![<alt-text>](<img-link>)`

I think the parenthesis need to be escaped here, but I'm not sure how to escape these characters without including the escape character in the abbreviation as well.
What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Abbreviations come in the following forms (See `:h abbreviations`):

```
There are three types of abbreviations:

full-id   The "full-id" type consists entirely of keyword characters (letters
      and characters from 'iskeyword' option).  This is the most common
      abbreviation.

      Examples: "foo", "g3", "-1"

end-id    The "end-id" type ends in a keyword character, but all the other
      characters are not keyword characters.

      Examples: "#i", "..f", "$/7"

non-id    The "non-id" type ends in a non-keyword character, the other
      characters may be of any type, excluding space and tab.  {this type
      is not supported by Vi}

      Examples: "def#", "4/7$"
```

`,,img` can not be a `full-id` as it starts with `,`. It can not be `end-id` as all other characters have to be non-keyword characters. It can not be `non-id` either.

I would recommend changing your abbreviations. e.g. `img,,`

Answer (score 1):

In my attempts to reproduce your problem, I find that vim gives me an error due to the two commas in the left-hand side of your abbreviation, `,,img`.

These work for me:

```
iabbrev img ![<alt-text>](<img-link>)
iabbrev __img ![<alt-text>](<img-link>)
```

while this:

```
iabbrev ,,img ![<alt-text>](<img-link>)
```

gives me error:

> E474: Invalid argument

Comment: I had assumed it was the parenthesis that were causing the problem. Its unfortunate to hear the double comma is the real problem after all, a double comma is in such a convenient keyboard place and it almost never occurs in any human or programming language.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint... I agree the comma is nicely accessible as an abbreviation prefix, far more convenient than the underscore!